# RESTEasy @WrappedMap

Tags: xml, jaxb, jax-rs, resteasy

I am using RESTEasy to write a RESTful web service and trying to write a response that contains a HashMap.  The web service produces either JSON or XML.  The JSON map is correct, but the XML map has no content.  The RESTEasy @WrappedMap annotation is supposed to marshal Maps to XML.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Response")
public class RootResponse {
  private HashMap<String, String> test;
  public RootResponse() {
    test = new HashMap<String, String>();
    test.put("Fred", "Wilma");
    test.put("Barney", "Betty");
  }
  @XmlElement
  @WrappedMap(map="test", key="name", entry="spouse")
  public HashMap<String, String> getTest() {
    return this.test;
  }
}
```

JSON output:

```
{
  "test": {
    "Fred": "Wilma",
    "Barney": "Betty"
  }
}
```

XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Response>
  <test/>
</Response>
```

I get the same output if I leave out the @WrappedMap annotation.

Does @WrappedMap not work for properties?

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since you posted this question, but I still want to share what I have recently learnt in case someone else may stumble upon this question.

`@WrappedMap` according to [this documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/RESTEasy_Reference_Guide/JAXB_Map.html) only helps changing the name of the elements in the output XML. As to why you cannot get JAXB to output XML from the `HashMap`, I think [this page](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_your_favorite_class.html#HashMap) has the explanation.

Hope this helps.